# Surface Flinger,SurfaceView,Surface,SurfaceHolder and Bitmap is Android

Tags: android, surfaceview

I'm learning from the Documentation of Suface, Suface Flinger, SurfaceView, SurfaceHolder and Bitmap. I have found following definitions:

**Surface**
Surface is a collection of pixels. A Surface is an object holding pixels that are being composited to the screen. Every window you see on the screen (a dialog, your full-screen activity, the status bar) has its own surface that it draws in to, and Surface Flinger renders these to the final display in their correct Z-order. A surface typically has more than one buffer (usually two) to do double-buffered rendering: the application can be drawing its next UI state while the surface flinger is compositing the screen using the last buffer, without needing to wait for the application to finish drawing.

**SurfaceView**
This class is used to present a live camera preview to the user.
A SurfaceView is a special implementation of View that also creates its own dedicated Surface for the application to directly draw into (outside of the normal view hierarchy, which otherwise must share the single Surface for the window)

**Bitmap**
A Bitmap is a wrapper for collection of pixels,it is simply an array of pixels with some other convenient functions.

**Canvas**
Canvas is a class that contains all the drawing methods. It is similar to Graphics class in AWT/Swing in Java. It has all the logic on how to draw, a box etc. A Canvas operates on a Bitmap.

But I'm not clear about **SurfaceHolder** and **SurfaceFlinger** and according to above definition bitmap is also container of pixel and Surface too.

Can you help to give me clear understanding the definition of all these objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Canvas is a basic context for doing drawing with the graphics API. You can create your own Canvas wrapping a Bitmap for doing off-screen drawing, and of course the UI framework will pass Canvases to widgets for them to draw themselves into. All these widgets are subclasses of View. Or, if they can contain other widgets, then they subclass from ViewGroup (which is a subclass of View).

If you want to do high-frame-rate animations, then you need to subclass from SurfaceView (or its subclass GLSurfaceView, if you want to do on-screen OpenGL-ES rendering). Each SurfaceView has a SurfaceHolder, which has lockCanvas methods that you can call at any time to get a Canvas into which to draw an updated display and post back for the user to see immediately via unlockCanvasAndPost.

For more info, see [2D graphics concepts](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=2d_graphics_concepts) and [Custom widget tips](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Custom_widget_tips)